# ddrescue image size on disk

Tags: disk-image, ddrescue

I am using ddrescue on a damaged disk.  When I began the recovery, I was saving the image to a local external drive.  Then, since I needed to remove the external, I changed the location of the image to be stored on a network share.  Everything seems to be working okay but I'm concerned that the "size on disk" is zero while the "Total size of files" is 329GB.  Is this normal?  Is there any way I can check to see what's really going on?  I've included some screenshots.
[image]
[image: Size_on_disk]

Comment: what filesystem is used on the remote network share?
what does a simple "ls -l" show you?
does 329GB correspond to the size of "/dev/sdc"?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Filesystem on share is NTFS.  On share  size on disk matches the size it should be.  "/dev/sdc" is a 500GB drive.  "ls-l" shows contents of my user folder.  (I couldn't figure out how to post another screenshot.)

Comment: Could the "size on disk" be zero because the image isn't actually "on" the disk and is on the share instead?  This is just a weird phenomenon I've never noticed before.  Size is now 423GB so I'm keeping my fingers crossed that everything's okay.